# Hide UI/Image partially in Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does Unity 5 support partial hiding of a UI/Image?

For example, the UI/Image I have in my scene has 100 width and 100 height.
At `time = 0`, the UI/Image is hidden. When `time = 5`, the UI/Image only shows the first 50 pixels. When `time = 10`, the UI/Image is fully drawn.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to the question is in this [link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/843551/how-to-crop-ui-image.html)

1. Set the image type to **Filled**
2. Set the fill method to **horizontal**
3. Set the fill origin to **left**
4. From the script, update the fill amount from 0 to 1 over the timespan

Answer (score 0):

On first thought, I can come up with two workarounds for this.

1. If the background of the image-in-question is a solid color, you can use another image with the same color as background that covers the actual image, so that it looks like the actual image is partially revealed. Then, just reduce the length of this covering image over time to achieve a revealing effect using [Coroutines](http://docs.unity3d.com/460/Documentation/Manual/Coroutines.html).
2. You make multiple image files with alpha channels and change the textures of the UI/Image over time. Each image will act like an iteration of revealing effect. Say you have 11 images, the 6th image will have first half revealed, and second half as alpha=0. In this case, if you want smoothness, you will need a higher number of images.

Comment: the UI/Image I have is with a transparent background.